# Run multiple tasks with the same command?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I want to **chain up some commands / tasks** I defined in `tasks.json`.

I have many different sub-projects (C# `csproj` files) that should be built, then tested (shell commands) in a big single task.

I have this [`tasks.json`](https://gist.github.com/eppz/f941f2e85e12e7cc81c63ee2ac1354e5) working, but I can only invoke the different commands one by one.

Comment: What do you mean you can only invoke them one by one? Can you provide more details of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Sure, thanks for getting back. I want to press a button, then have my 6 sub-projects built, then have 6 test commands ran. Actually that's all.

Comment: Is there a way to define a task dependency, or similar?

Comment: You can add your commands as post build steps in visual studio. How are you invoking your tasks currently.

Comment: Yap, thanks, I'm trying to use VS Code here, not Visual Studio (see tags).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, there is a **`dependsOn`** property since 1.10. 
See [More work on Terminal Runner](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_10#_more-work-on-terminal-runner) in release notes.

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks":
    [
        {
            "taskName": "Build",
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "command": "/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/MonoBleedingEdge/bin/xbuild",
            "args":
            [
                "Project.sln",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true"
            ],
            "showOutput": "silent",
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        {
            "taskName": "Build EPPZ.Extensions.Test",
            "command": "/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/MonoBleedingEdge/bin/xbuild",
            "args":
            [
                "Assets/Plugins/eppz!/Extensions/Test.csproj",
                "/property:Configuration=Local",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true"
            ],
            "showOutput": "always",
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        {
            "taskName": "Test EPPZ.Extensions.Test",
            "isShellCommand": true,
            "command": "mono",
            "dependsOn": [ "Build EPPZ.Extensions.Test" ],
            "args":
            [
                "/Users/eppz/Projects/Unity/Packages/NUnit/NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.6.1/tools/nunit3-console.exe",
                "bin/EPPZ.Extensions.Test.dll",
                "--labels=All",
                "--result=EPPZ.Extensions.Test.Result.xml"
            ],
            "showOutput": "always"
        },
        {
            "taskName": "Test",
            "isShellCommand": true,
            "isTestCommand": true,
            "command": "echo",
            "args": ["All done."],
            "dependsOn": [ "Test (EPPZ.Extensions.Test)" ],
            "showOutput": "always"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Good find. They need to update their docs because I don't see any mention of `dependsOn` in the documents for tasks. This is exactly what I was looking for, but it is kind of odd that you have to essentially define your tasks in reverse order.

Comment: Yeah, I spotted this on GitHub in some random `tasks.json` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

After getting further clarification, what you are trying to accomplish can be configured as post build steps in Visual Studio. Configure the commands for the last project that will build.

[image]

*Original Answer*

---

You can execute your tasks in parallel:

```
public class TaskCollection
{
    public string version { get; set; }
    public List<Task> tasks { get; set; }
    public static void RunTasks()
    {
        string json = new WebClient().DownloadString("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/eppz/f941f2e85e12e7cc81c63ee2ac1354e5/raw/fa15f7b9774083f481504677b96353fe0da777be/tasks.json");
        TaskCollection col = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<TaskCollection>(json);
        Parallel.ForEach(col.tasks, (x) =>
        {
            ExecuteTask(x);
        }
        );
    }

    private static void ExecuteTask(Task x)
    {
        //Do something
    }
}

public class Task
{
    public string taskName { get; set; }
    public bool isBuildCommand { get; set; }
    public string command { get; set; }
    public string[] args { get; set; }
    public string showOutput { get; set; }
    public string problemMatcher { get; set; }
    public bool isShellCommand { get; set; }
    public bool isTestCommand { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Wow, you're fast.   I was thinking about this as an option, as I could hook up any command in a `.csproj` file, but I'd like to specify this in VS Code to have things organized / explicit.

Comment: You could put this code in a standalone `.csproj` and run it as a task. You can use the settings from your json to control what that does. For example, start a `Process` that runs a unit test and then returns. Your unit test will execute but VSCode can continue on to its next task because it is not waiting for your unit tests to complete.

Comment: what is this visual studio answer doing here with a question about visual studio code?